# Field filter within the grid

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'm not good at English.

I want to know if it is possible to filter field in grid.

I have a problem I am filtering a field, but it is not updated in selector, where it should show what I want.

here I show an image.

I will thank you all very much.

[image]

here I put the code I did:

#region CategoryID

```
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Category ID")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<PESKPriceIndexCat.categoryID,
         Where<PESKPriceIndexCat.state, Equal<Current<stateID>>,
         And<PESKPriceIndexCat.active, Equal<True>>>>),
        typeof(PESKPriceIndexCat.categoryID), 
        typeof(PESKPriceIndexCat.categoryCD),
        typeof(PESKPriceIndexCat.descripcion), 
        DescriptionField = typeof(PESKPriceIndexCat.descripcion), SubstituteKey = 
       typeof(PESKPriceIndexCat.categoryCD))]
    public virtual int? CategoryID { get; set; }
    public abstract class categoryID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<categoryID> { }

  #endregion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the selector in the DAC seems to be correct, therefore one possible solution would be to set the AutoRefresh property on the selector from the layout editor to true and the SyncPosition property on the grid to true as well. With these two properties the current value will update on row change and when opening the selector it will automatically refresh with the correct dataset.

Comment: thanks for the answer, you were right, the SyncPosition property "True" is missing

Comment: @Tibu - If this answer is correct, make sure to accept it as the answer by selecting the checkmark beside it.